# Acumatica scheduler

Tags: scheduler, acumatica

This might be a strange question.  Is there any way to make the scheduler stay active perpetually?  I have a couple of instances, one on a server for testing and a development instance on my laptop.  I setup some business events in both instances that accurately fire as designed. My question comes from the fact that the scheduler seems to stall if no one logs into the instance.  Once I login to the instance with any id, the scheduler restarts and runs for about 12 hours and then stalls again.  I thought it was only the test instance on the server, but I took a couple days off and my laptop instance also stalled.  Is there a setting to overcome this?  I know the assumption is that there will be users in the system in production, but what about over the weekend or holidays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schedule is run from the IIS worker process (w3wp) of the assigned Application Pool. Normally the worker process is started when the first web request is received.

If you restart the test instance of the server or your laptop instance you may experience this delay until someone logs in.

However, you can set the worker process to start automatically whenever an Application Pool starts.

Check your IIS configuration, look for the Application Pool assigned to your Acumatica instance and edit its Advanced Settings.

[image]

There you can change `StartMode` to `AlwaysRunning`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Made the change and I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Your app pool might be recycled. Check the following posts that can help you

[How to know who kills my threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675910/how-to-know-who-kills-my-threads#answer-2817705)

https://serverfault.com/questions/333907/what-should-i-do-to-make-sure-that-iis-does-not-recycle-my-application